# Using variable for getItem (sessionStorage and localStorage) instead of a string

Tags: jquery, session, session-variables

I'm using `sessionStorage` to save CSS changes by jQuery.

I can get everything to work great, except for this last step.  Basically, if I request `sessionStorage.getItem()` with a string that I manually type in, it works but if I use a variable, it doesn't recognize the value... even if a convert to string. Thanks, in advance, for any tips.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('name', 'mike');

sessionStorage.getItem('name');
```

Works fine but when I use a variable, even when forcing into a string... No errors or returned value.

```
var x = 'mike';
x.toString();

sessionStorage.setItem('name', x);

sessionStorage.getItem(x);
```

Comment: get item ('name') not x -- check here on how it works -- https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/

Answer (score 0):

When you use `sessionStorage.getItem(key)`, you pass it the *key* of the item in session storage. In your above code, `sessionStorage.getItem(x)` is equivalent to `sessionStorage.getItem('mike')`, (because you set `x = 'mike'`) which is the value, not the key. If you did `var y = 'name'` and then `sessionStorage.getItem(y)` you would get your value back.

Comment: First, thanks for quick response and I apologize because I messed up my question.  What I really need to do is 

sessionStorage.setItem('mike', 'absent');

sessionStorage.getItem('mike');

Comment: If you change it then that will work. For example the following code logs 'absent' to the console: `var x = 'mike'; sessionStorage.setItem(x, 'absent'); console.log(sessionStorage.getItem(x));`

Comment: Your mistake is that the argument you are passing to `sessionStorage.getItem(x)` is the *value* of the pair in session storage, when it should be the *key*.

Comment: I know this is really late but wanted to say thanks for help.  Finally got it fixed.